# How to disable the textfield in textfomrfield?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im using a textformfield for validation and the form but not for text  what I want is let user picking date. So heres my problem how can I disable the that on tap on the textfield opens the keyboard so I can just show my Datepicker?Heres my widget

```
 String _date = "Please pick Age";

  Widget _buildage() {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      Text(
        'Enter Age',
        style: kLabelStyle,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
              theme: DatePickerTheme(
                containerHeight: 210.0,
              ),
              showTitleActions: true,
              minTime: DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
              maxTime: DateTime(2022, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
            print('confirm $date');

            setState(() {
              _date = '${date.year} - ${date.month} - ${date.day}';
            });
          }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          height: 60.0,
          child: Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.date_range_rounded,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 28,
                ),
                hintText: " $_date",
                hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

Hope anyone can help I also using some other Textformfield but I only want to disable this on in the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In textformfield, set `readOnly: true`. You can also use the `onTap` property of the textformfield, so you won't have to use the gesture detector.

```
TextFormField(
readOnly: true,
onTap: ()=>your function)
```

Comment: ok got it  but another question do you know why im getting this error   ../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.
 - 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.

                  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
                               ^

Comment: I see that you posted a new question regarding your new issue. Please consider marking this answer as a solution to the problem in this post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386501/how-to-deal-the-limit-of-whereinWould you maybe check this one out . Thanks for this answer bro